# batch file doesnt show parameters assigned

Tags: sql, batch-file

I am using the following batch file:

```
call e:\utility\batfiles\DBAEnvProd.cmd

svr2=AS-RISCSQL199
set dbname=UMRdb

set proc=UMRdb.[dbo].[spmaintenancemode] @server= ="%svr2%"
echo proc
call %osqlExeLocation% -E -d%dbname% -S%svr1% -w%w% -b -Q"exec %proc%" -o%pathout%%Maintmode.txt

set proc=UMRdb.[dbo].[spmaintenancemodedate] @server= "%svr2%"
call %osqlExeLocation% -E -d%dbname% -S%svr1% -w%w% -b -Q"exec %proc%" -o%pathout%%Maintmodedate.txt
```

It is not accessing server name. I tried all option taking parameters as

```
set proc=UMRdb.[dbo].[spmaintenancemode] @server= ="%svr2%"
set proc=UMRdb.[dbo].[spmaintenancemode] @server= ='%svr2%'
set proc=UMRdb.[dbo].[spmaintenancemode] @server= =%svr2%
```

but the parameters are empty.

What am I doing wrong in setting the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

need to write
set svr2=AS-RISCSQL199
instead of svr2=AS-RISCSQL199